# Manejar un type de SQL desde java

Tags: java, sql, plsql

Tengo un plSql que me devuelve un type de datos.

Cómo puedo manejar estos desde java, me explico, hago la llamada a el PL desde java, pero no se como recoger ese type de respuesta para poder usar sus campos.

Comment: Por favor provee el código relevante para comprender mejor tu problema.

Comment: ¡Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! ☺ No olvides visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Respecto a tu pregunta, por *type* ¿te refieres al atributo `%TYPE` o al atributo `%ROWTYPE`? Realmente necesitas incluir más detalles en tu pregunta para que la comunidad pueda responder satisfactoriamente. En el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) encontrarás [*¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/21649/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No das mucha información, pero si lo que te refieres es a tipos PLSQL como STRUCT o ARRAY de Oracle, lo que necesitas es usar `OracleCallableStatement` que te provee métodos para registrar parámetros de salida de esos tipos.

Ejemplo:

```
Transaction tran = null;
OracleCallableStatement ocs = null;

try {
    tran = ...obtener transaccion...
    tran.setSql( "CALL PROPIETARIO.PAQUETE.PROCEDIMIENTO(?,?)" );
    ocs = (OracleCallableStatement) tran.prepareCall();

    ocs.setString(1, "UN_PARAMETRO_DE_ENTRADA");
    ocs.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.STRUCT, "NOMBRE_DEL_TIPO_PLSQL");

    ocs.execute();

    //la clase padre es oracle.sql.Datum y de ella heredan STRUCT y ARRAY.
    oracle.sql.STRUCT struct = ocs.getSTRUCT(2);

    Object[] atributos = (Object[])struct.getAttributes();

    //El array de atributos esta ordenado tal cual se declaran las propiedades en el plsql, así que si por ejemplo el primer campo es un nombre.
    String nombre = (String)atributos[0];
    ...etc...

}catch( Excetion ex){
    //manejar excepciones;
}
```

Los `Datum` se pueden mandar también como parámetros de entrada, no solo de salida, incluso ambas cosas a la vez.

Actualmente con JPA no solemos usar mucho este tipo de mapeos, pero antiguamente, definíamos un Bean con los mismo campos que el STRUCT oracle e implementabamos un interface similar a este:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import oracle.sql.Datum;

/**
 * Interface que define los métodos necesarios para transformar un objeto
 * entre el tipo Java y el Oracle.
 * @author Victor Gimeno
 * @version 1.0
 */
public interface OracleBdParser {

    /**
     * Método que transforma el objeto a un tipo Oracle de BBDD.
     * @param con Objeto con la conexion a la bbdd para hacer un lookup del objeto.
     * @return Supertipo de los objetos Oracle en Java
     * @throws SQLException excepcion de base de datos
     */
    Datum toSqlOracleType( Connection con ) throws SQLException;

    /**
     * Método que transforma el objeto a un tipo Oracle de BBDD.
     * @param oracleObj Objeto de tipo Oracle que debe transformarse
     * @throws SQLException excepcion de base de datos
     */
    void fromSqlOracleType( Datum oracleObj ) throws SQLException;

    /**
     * Método que devuelve el Nombre del tipo de Objeto Oracle declarado en BBDD.
     * @return Nombre del Objeto declaro en BBDD.
     */
    String getSqlOracleTypeName();
}
```

Así a la hora de recuperarlo de base de datos simplemente invocabamos:

```
mibean.fromSqlOracleType(ocs.getSTRUCT(2));
```

Espero que te sirva,
Un saludo.